# Set status in java

Tags: java, iterator

So i wrote this part of the application. It works but not all the time.

```
public void setStatus(int id, int area, boolean free)
{
    Iterator<Ambulance> ab = cars.iterator();
    while(ab.hasNext()){
        Ambulance ambulance = ab.next();
        if(ambulance.getID() == id){
            ambulance.moveTo(area);
            ambulance.setBusy();
        }  
    }

}
```

For this setStatus, I have this test condition but this part `assertEquals(!oldStatus, selected.isFree());` of the condition does not work. What should I do?

```
public void moveAmbulance()
{
    // Select a random Ambulance to be moved.
    Ambulance selected = shadow.get(rand.nextInt(shadow.size()));
    int oldArea = selected.getArea();
    boolean oldStatus = selected.isFree();
    control.setStatus(selected.getID(), oldArea + 1, !oldStatus);
    assertEquals(oldArea + 1, selected.getArea());
    assertEquals(!oldStatus, selected.isFree());
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You can replace the `while` loop with an enhanced `for` loop: `for (Ambulance ambulance : cars) { … }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public void setStatus(int id, int area, boolean free)
{
    Iterator<Ambulance> ab = cars.iterator();
    while(ab.hasNext()){
        Ambulance ambulance = ab.next();
        if(ambulance.getID() == id){
            ambulance.moveTo(area);
        }
        if(free){
            ambulance.setFree();
        } else{
            ambulance.setBusy();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to write a brief description about your code to explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `free` parameter in the `setStatus` method

```
public void setStatus(int id, int area, boolean free)
{
    Iterator<Ambulance> ab = cars.iterator();
    while(ab.hasNext()){
        Ambulance ambulance = ab.next();
        if ((free) && (ambulance.getID() == id)) {
            ambulance.moveTo(area);
            ambulance.setBusy();
        }  
    }
}
```